# Deploying app with webpack on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, webpack

I've some troubles trying to deploy the project to Heroku, it works local, but on Heroku, there's a message "Application error". I appreciate any guide or support to know what I'm doing bad.

As far I could see the build doesn't seem to have any problem, but trying to access to the web, it's fatal.

Github: 
https://github.com/gpincheiraa/angularjs-tdd-jest/tree/heroku_deploy

Web: 
https://still-plains-66291.herokuapp.com/

This is the error log

```
2017-10-28T00:04:11.032366+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node start`
2017-10-28T00:04:12.859627+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:515
2017-10-28T00:04:12.859643+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2017-10-28T00:04:12.859644+00:00 app[web.1]:     ^
2017-10-28T00:04:12.859644+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-10-28T00:04:12.859645+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '/app/start'
2017-10-28T00:04:12.859646+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:513:15)
2017-10-28T00:04:12.859646+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:463:25)
2017-10-28T00:04:12.859647+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:653:10)
2017-10-28T00:04:12.859647+00:00 app[web.1]:     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
2017-10-28T00:04:12.859647+00:00 app[web.1]:     at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
2017-10-28T00:04:12.914674+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-10-28T00:04:12.926370+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-10-28T00:04:12.928677+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-10-28T00:04:17.672129+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node start`
2017-10-28T00:04:19.618524+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:515
2017-10-28T00:04:19.618541+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2017-10-28T00:04:19.618542+00:00 app[web.1]:     ^
2017-10-28T00:04:19.618543+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-10-28T00:04:19.618544+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '/app/start'
2017-10-28T00:04:19.618545+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:513:15)
2017-10-28T00:04:19.618546+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:463:25)
2017-10-28T00:04:19.618547+00:00 app[web.1]:     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
2017-10-28T00:04:19.618546+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:653:10)
2017-10-28T00:04:19.618548+00:00 app[web.1]:     at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
2017-10-28T00:04:19.695816+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-10-28T00:04:19.681446+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

And the build log

```
-----> Node.js app detected
-----> Creating runtime environment

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=development
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  >=8.4.0
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)

       Resolving node version >=8.4.0...
       Downloading and installing node 8.8.1...
       Detected package-lock.json: defaulting npm to version 5.x.x
       Bootstrapping npm 5.x.x (replacing 5.4.2)...
       npm 5.5.1 installed
-----> Restoring cache
       Loading 2 from cacheDirectories (default):
       - node_modules
       - bower_components (not cached - skipping)
-----> Building dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)

       > angularjs-tdd-jest@0.5.0 postinstall /tmp/build_47259e9fbff603f69b77278096c651b4/glabrat-angularjs-tdd-jest-1d7f548
       > NODE_ENV=development webpack -p --config webpack.dev.js --progress

     Hash: 53ea942157bbfc80ca9c
       Version: webpack 3.8.1
       Time: 4039ms
       Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
       index.bundle.js  4.53 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  app
       [52] ./src/index.js 719 bytes {0} [built]
       [54] ./src/routes.js 607 bytes {0} [built]
       [57] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 488 bytes {0} [built]
       [82] ./src/services/todo.service.js 1.36 kB {0} [built]
       + 79 hidden modules
       added 115 packages in 14.844s
-----> Caching build
       Clearing previous node cache
       Saving 2 cacheDirectories (default):
       - node_modules
       - bower_components (nothing to cache)
-----> Build succeeded!
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 47M
-----> Launching...
       Released v10
       https://still-plains-66291.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

Comment: what are u actually starting  ie what scripts section in 'package.json' ?

Comment: did you try running 'heroku local'

Comment: Thanks, I used 'heroku local' and I could reproduce the error
My scripts are https://github.com/gpincheiraa/angularjs-tdd-jest/blob/heroku_deploy/package.json#L10